# Photo-swipe is not loading in my website

Tags: media, javascript

I'm using drupal -7 with mobile_jquery(https://drupal.org/project/mobile_jquery) as theme

and [PhotoSwipe](https://drupal.org/project/photoswipe) .

The PhotoSwipe is not working in the gallery page.When we click on the thumbnail ,the image will not load first time and show the blank screen with below message

> undefined

and we can see path of the image in the address-bar.***When we refresh the page the PS will work.But something missing ...***
website: http://www.w3qatar.info/aldarmobi .

***`properties >> please click on any property and you can find more images >> Click on any image to see the PS.`***

I don't know what is the reason for this.Please help me to solve this issue.

Please suggest me any other image gallery module which works on ios,android devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the [Juicebox](https://drupal.org/project/juicebox) module in my Drupal 7 site for swiping.  With my iPhone 4, it is working super. I have tried other solutions, without luck.  The free version of [Juicebox](http://www.juicebox.net/) allows you to place 50 pics in a box.

Comment: yes you are right.Currently i'm Juice box free version

Comment: Video tutorial on the integration between Drupal and Juicebox gallery can be found here also. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mAlrXU0MP0k